# How to override JAXB @XMLAccessorType(XMLAccessType.FIELD) specified at a Class level with @XMLElement on a getter method for a property?

Tags: jaxb, jax-rs

In the example code below, *Employee* class has been specified with JAXB field level access type. For the property *dept*, however, the access type has been specified at getter method level with *@XMLElement* annotation.

During marshalling of *Organization* class, the following exception is thrown -

```
com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Class has two properties of the same name "dept"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String com.playground.jaxb.Employee.getDept()
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private java.lang.String com.playground.jaxb.Employee.dept
```

Can you help me understand why this overriding of JAXB accessor type is not working please? Also any solution would be highly appreciated.

**Example**

**Root Element Class**

```
package com.playground.jaxb;

@XMLRootElement(name="organization")
public class Organization {

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "employees")
    @XmlElement(name = "employee")
    private Set<Employee> employees;

    public Organization{}

    // Remainder omitted...
}
```

**Employee Class**

```
package com.playground.jaxb;

@XMLAccessorType(XMLAccessType.FIELD)
public class Employee {

    private String name;

    private String dept;

    @XMLElement(name="department")
    public String getDept() {
        return dept;
    }

    public void setDept(String dept) {
        this.dept = dept;
    }

    public Employee {}

    // Remainder omitted...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can re-name getter/setter pair, e.g. `getDept()` -> `getDepartment()`

```
private String dept;

@XmlElement(name="department")
public String getDeptartment() {
    return dept;
}

public void setDeptartment(String dept) {
    this.dept = dept;
}
```

but in this case you will have duplicate in XML

```
   <dept>my_dept</dept>
   <department>my_dept</department>
```

Or you can annotate field `dept` with [@XmlTransient](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlTransient.html) annotation, if you want to change access type it.

```
@XmlTransient
private String dept;

@XmlElement(name="department")
public String getDept() {
    return dept;
}

public void setDept(String dept) {
    this.dept = dept;
}
```

In this case, `dept` field will be ignored and getter/setter pair will be used instead

Comment: Ilya - i prefer your second approach as it is more cleaner, and no-strings attached. i'm wondering, however, why we need to explicitly mention @XMLTransient on the field level though. wudn't it be easy for development if we get rid of this explicit annotation? - cud be a suggestion to JAXB team?! - Thanks

Comment: @V.Vidyasagar - In Java there isn't a real association between fields and their corresponding properties.  This is why we didn't add the behaviour in JAXB you are looking for.  Here is some additional info on JAXB access types: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html

Comment: Blaise - i understand that unlike languages such as Groovy - Java doesn't have much support or language level semantics for fields/corresponding properties. Nevertheless, i feel this feature (making @XMLTransient redundant) would be a nice to have for development if not a must have. - Thanks